# Evaluate the limit using Riemann Sums

Tags: real-analysis, limits, summation

I'm working on a problem for a preliminary exam, and I came across one that confused me.

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$, set

$t_n=\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{2n+i}=\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}+\cdots+\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n}$

Evaluate $\lim_{n\to\infty} nt_n$

$\textit{Hint:}$ Relate the given limit to suitable Riemann sums for $f(x)=(1+x)^{-2}$.

I've evaluated limits using Riemann sums before, and I've simplified

$\lim_{n\to\infty}nt_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}n(\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{2n+i})=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\frac{1}{2n}\sum_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{(-1)^{i+1}}{1+\frac{i}{2n}}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^{2n}(-1)^{i+1}\sqrt{f(\frac{i}{2n})}$

This is as far as I've been able to complete however. I am confused as to the alternating nature of the sum, and how to complete the limit problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If $t_n=\frac{1}{2n+1}-\frac{1}{2n+2}+\frac{1}{2n+3}-\frac{1}{2n+4}+\cdots +\frac{1}{4n-1}-\frac{1}{4n}$. Find $\lim_{n \to \infty} nt_n$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3181789/if-t-n-frac12n1-frac12n2-frac12n3-frac12n4-cdots-fra) (the last answer is based on Riemann sums).

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's one way to do it,

$t_n=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{2n}\frac{\left(-1\right)^{i+1}}{2n+i}=\sum\limits_{i\leq2n,i\in\mathrm{Odds}}\frac1{2n+i}-\sum\limits_{i\leq2n,i\in\mathrm{Evens}}\frac1{2n+i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{2n+2i-1}-\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{2n+2i}=\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{\left(2n+2i-1\right)\left(2n+2i\right)}=\frac1{4n^2}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{\left(1+\frac{i-\frac12}n\right)\left(1+\frac in\right)}$

So,

$nt_n=\frac1{4n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\frac1{\left(1+\frac{i-\frac12}n\right)\left(1+\frac in\right)}$.

This is a Riemann sum, that is,

$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}nt_n=\frac14\int_0^1\frac{\mathrm dx}{\left(1+x\right)^2}=\frac18$